# Remote database event listener Java Spring Boot, PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I was looking for database listener for my microservice based java project. Some of the services are sharing the same remote jdbc connection.
I tried this but its not giving logs of remote DB, just inside listener of project:

```java
@PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
        EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_INSERT).appendListener(new InsertEventListener());
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_UPDATE).appendListener(new UpdateEventListener());
    }
```

This listener should connect to a remote postgresql DB and start listening events like "some entity inserted" or "some entity updated" etc.

Is there any maven dep. that already done this before ?

Comment: Maybe someone else coded it custom before, any suggestions are ok.

Comment: These event listeners are listening to the activity in *that EntityManager* only. So it will only be events that originate in the same service that will show up. If you want to have one service notified of changes made from a different service, you will need to use something like [pgjdbc-ng](http://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/) which is capable of hooking into the Postgres LISTEN/NOTIFY features.